# парсинг json в интерфейс

Tags: json, vkontakte-api, golang, golang-struct

пишу парсер longpoll событий вк, столкнулся с проблемой

```
json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field LongPollEventUpdate.updates.object of type vkapi.LongPollUpdateObject
```

вот собственно код

```go
package vkapi

type LongPollEvent struct {
    TS      string                `json:"ts"`
    Updates []LongPollEventUpdate `json:"updates"`
}

type LongPollEventUpdate struct {
    Type   string               `json:"type"`
    Object LongPollUpdateObject `json:"object"`
}

type LongPollUpdateObject interface {
    LongPollInterfaceDummy()
}

func (LongPollWallPostNew) LongPollInterfaceDummy() {}

type LongPollWallPostNew struct {
    ID          int    `json:"id"`
    FromID      int    `json:"from_id"`
    OwnerID     int    `json:"owner_id"`
    Date        int    `json:"date"`
    MarkedAsAds int    `json:"marked_as_ads"`
    PostType    string `json:"post_type"`
    Text        string `json:"text"`
    CanEdit     int    `json:"can_edit"`
    CreatedBy   int    `json:"created_by"`
    CanDelete   int    `json:"can_delete"`
    Comments    struct {
        Count int `json:"count"`
    } `json:"comments"`
}
```

почему вот json.Unmarshal не может распарсить кусок JSON в мой интерфейс?

Comment: Если вы добавите достаточно рабочего кода и пример вашего json текста как есть, то вы получите более информативный ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не понятно, чего вы ожидаете?  Декодер доходит до вашего интерфейса
и что он по-вашему должен сделать?  Просканировать весь мир и найти «ту
самую» имплементацию интерфейса?  Такой магии в *Go* нет.  Либо
ставьте в этом месте конкретный тип, либо заворачивайте интерфейс
в обёрточный тип, который в свою очередь имплементирует интерфейс
[`enconding/json.Unmarshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler).